# Aggregate $expr throws duplicate element name in Bson syntax C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I am trying to convert this MongoDB query, which works on Robo3T, to the equivalent in C# using Bson syntax.

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([{ "$match" : { "$expr" : { "$gt" : ["$property1", "$property2"], "$gt" : ["$property1", "$property3"] } } }])
```

it is throwing exception when I try to run this code:

```
return new List<BsonDocument>
{
    new BsonDocument
    {
        {
            "$match", new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "$expr", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {
                            "$gt", new BsonArray 
                            {
                                "$property1", "$property2"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$gt", new BsonArray
                            {
                                "$property1", "$property3"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```
Duplicate element name '$gt'.
   at MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.Add(BsonElement element)
   at MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.Add(String name, BsonValue value)
 ...
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a workaround solution by adding the two `$gt` inside a `$and`.

```
return new List<BsonDocument>
{
    new BsonDocument
    {
        {
            "$match", new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "$expr", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {
                            "$and", new BsonArray
                            {
                                new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {
                                        "$gt", new BsonArray 
                                        {
                                            "$property1", "$property2"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {
                                        "$gt", new BsonArray 
                                        {
                                            "$property1", "$property3"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```